# edit file without swap file within a vim session

Tags: swap-file

The only workaround I can come up with is after opening a vim session:

```
:set updatecount=0 | e +setlocal\ noswapfile FILENAME | set updatecount&
```

Are there any shorter vim commands or options that could achieve the same effect?

Comment: make a function, wrap all special needs (set x,set y set z, mapping, au....) for your particular session, when you need it, just call the function by a custom command/mapping

Comment: Could you go into more detail?  Why do you want to disable the swap file and does this involve any particular file type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [`:noswapfile e FILENAME`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/recover.txt.html#:nos):

```
  :nos[wapfile]   {command}         *:nos* *:noswapfile*
        Execute {command}. If it contains a command that loads a new
        buffer, it will be loaded without creating a swapfile and the
        'swapfile' option will be reset.  If a buffer already had a
        swapfile it is not removed and 'swapfile' is not reset.
```

But keep in mind that usually there are better solutions, depending on what you are trying to achieve, because without a swap file you are more likely to lose your work.